# 1D Array to fill a spreadsheet column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the built-in group service to pull a list of usernames...

```
function getUsersInGroup(group) {
  var usersInGroup = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(group).getUsers();
  return usersInGroup;
}
```

...and it returns an array, like this...

```
[ person1@email.com, person2@email.com, person3@email.com ]
```

What I would like is for those emails to show up in a spreadsheet column like this...
[image: Email addresses in column A of a spreadsheet. Each value is in a separate row.]

It seems that Apps Script's .setValues() wants a 2D array, even when the data is "flat", so I get the impression from my tests that my data has to be in a format like this...

```
var data = [[person1@email.com],[person2@email.com],[person3@email.com]]
```

If I want it to show up as rows of data instead of one item in a column.

If I'm correct, I think I'm looking for the best of two (maybe three) possible answers to my question.

**What I think are Possible solutions**

1. Transform the array and make each item in the array a one item array
   with probably a for loop
2. Find out there is a better built-in function that will take the
   array and turn it into a row of data
3. There's something else I could do that I didn't even consider here

Comment: You could use the array.forEach method.  usersInGroup.forEach(function(user,i,usersInGroup) { usersInGroup[i] = [user]; });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  can also use the sheets API, If you don't want to loop through.

Use [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range) and  switching majorDimension as columns:

```
  var data = [ 'person1@email.com', 'person2@email.com', 'person3@email.com' ];
  var request = {
    range: 'Sheet1!A1',
    majorDimension: 'COLUMNS',
    values: [data], //still 2D
  };
  //API must be enabled before use. 
  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(request, ss.getId(), request.range, {
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  });
```

Or loop through:

```
data = data.map(function(e){return [e];});
```

Comment: I tried forEach( function(b) { return [b]; } at first but it didn't work.  So then expanded to forEach( function(b,i,a) { a[i] = b; }.  But I like TheMaster map() better.

Comment: @TheWizEd It's because [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)'s ``return`` value is `undefined`. It doesn't return anything- but you can use it to make changes in place(like how you used).

Comment: @cjm API is faster, if the number of records are large.

Comment: @TheMaster, good point. Working with less than 100 records in this case.

Comment: @cjm Then I guess it won't make a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

As @TheMaster pointed out, a simple loop with the map function worked well. Here's what I did:

```
function writeArrayToColumn(array) {
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 

  var newArray = array.map(function (el) {
    return [el];
  });

  var range = mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, newArray.length, 1);

  range.setValues(newArray);
}
```