# How to Set Values with Array and match length

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting a list of data from an external API and when I'm doing the setValues() it deliver an error:

The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 365. (line 59, file "Extra_queries")

I've tried deleting the length of the columns on set values and also changing the order.

I think the array is not well built. I think this array is being set for columns and not for rows?
Range expected is on Row 3, column 16 until the end of data.

```
function getComments(doc){
  var basicMetadata = getDeliveryBasicMetadata()
  var ordersId = doc.getRange("C3:C").getValues();
  var last_row = ordersId.filter(String).length;
  var range = doc.getRange(3,16,last_row,1);
  var comments = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= last_row; ++i){
    var orderIndex = i-3
    var comment = lookForComments(ordersId[orderIndex],basicMetadata);
    comments.push(comment);
  }
  var setValuesLenght = last_row - 2 //as we start on row 3 to align Last_row with lenght of the comments Array. Now both 365
  doc.getRange(3,16,setValuesLenght,1).setValues([comments]);
}
```

Here you can see the array that is built with comments.(lots of "" because this is a test)

[image]

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution doing the loop explained on: [1D Array to fill a spreadsheet column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090460/1d-array-to-fill-a-spreadsheet-column?rq=1)

Thank you ross for your help!

See working code:

```
  function getComments(doc){
  var basicMetadata = getDeliveryBasicMetadata()
  var ordersId = doc.getRange("C3:C").getValues();
  var last_row = ordersId.filter(String).length;
  var comments =[]
  for each (order in ordersId){
    comments.push(lookForComments(order,basicMetadata));
  } 
  writeArrayToColumn(comments, doc)
}


function writeArrayToColumn(array, mainSheet) {
  var newArray = array.map(function (el) {
    return [el];
  });
  mainSheet.getRange(3,16,newArray.length,1).setValues(newArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

Your array is 1-dimensional, not 2-dimensional like you're expecting. Since this is the case, it will only ever be 1 row long.

---

#### Solution:

```
doc.getRange(3,16,1,comments.length).setValues([comments]);
```

Comment: I've done it but it still shows the same issue: Message details
The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 365.

Comment: Then it might be an issue with what your function `lookForComments()` is returning - could you include it in the question? Also, could you do a `Logger.log(comments.length);` and show the output?

Comment: I've Shared screenshot of Logs.  The array of comments is like this. [comment1, comment2,....] .     loofForCommnets() is working properly as it works with setValue 1 by one.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Array comments. It is understanding data as columns and not rows?

Comment: Yes - it's a 1-dimensional array but you're expecting a 2-dimensional array. Since it's 1-dimensional it'll only ever be 1 row, then you can pass `comments.length` as the argument for `numColumns` in your `getRange()`.