# Google Sheets App Script: Can you write an array to a single row instead of a single column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

The method `.setValues()` will take an array `[[0],[1],[2],[3]]` and write it to the `.getRange()` which has to be in multiple rows in a single column: A1, A2, A3, A4.

Instead, I want to write the same array but write it to a single row: A1, B1, C1, D1. Is this possible or do I have to rearrange my arrays to always write to a single column?

Edit: I'm sorry I think I was unclear. I am basically looking for a method or something similar to the appendRow method using an array. The array can be 1D or 2D (I can easily write a loop to create either). The reason appendRow doesn't work for me is because this method will place the array at the bottom of the data. I would like to place the row of data in a range I can specify.

For example, using the array above, I would like to write that array to getRange(1,4,1,4) with data already existing in getRange(1,3,10,10).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1D Array to fill a spreadsheet column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090460/1d-array-to-fill-a-spreadsheet-column)

Comment: See [majorDimension here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //  var dataArray = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dataArray = [[0],[1],[2],[3]]
  var dataUnit;
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    dataUnit = dataArray[i].toString();
    data.push(dataUnit);
  }
  ss.appendRow(data);
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're turning the 2D array into a 1d array in order to be able to use the appendRow method. Is there a way to specify the range in which you write the row of data instead of appending to the bottom of the current data? As far as I know, appendRow can only place a row at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. You can always use `getRange()` (the way I've done in my code right above `var dataArray = [[0],[1],[2],[3]] `) & use `setValues()` :)

Comment: Ah you're right! I was trying to setValues([[1], [2], [3]]) or setValues([1, 2, 3]).. I didn't think to try setValues([[1, 2, 3]]) which worked to write to a row. Thanks! Beginner dummy moment

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
var dataArray = [[0],[1],[2],[3]].reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});

Logger.log(dataArray); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or, if you need a 2D-array (required by .setValues())

```
var dataArray = [[[0],[1],[2],[3]].reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
})];
Logger.log(dataArray); // [[0, 1, 2, 3]] --> 2D array representing a single row.
```